# Node + MySQLで、プレースホルダを用いてUPDATEしたい

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

以下のようにMySQLのテーブル情報をとってきて、押すボタンによって処理を振り分けたいと思っております。
しかし、updatesqlのようにプレースホルダが2つある場合、どのようにnode側で指定してあげればよいのか分かりません。

```js
const checksql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
const checkname = "SELECT status FROM users WHERE name = ?";

const updatesql = "UPDATE users SET ? WHERE ?";

if(req.body.begin_button){
    var name_checked = await query(checksql,{ name: req.body.input_name });
    var status_checked = await query(checkname,{ name: req.body.input_name});

if(name_checked == 0){
      var results = await query(sql, { id: id, name: req.body.input_name, email: req.body.input_mail, start: now, status: 1 });
    }else{
      console.log("error");
    };
  }
  else if(req.body.finish_button){
    if(name_checked != 0){
      var results = await query(updatesql, { end: now, status: 0});
    }else{
      console.log("error");
    }
  }
  else if(req.body.start_button){
    if(status_checked == 1){
      var results = await query(updatesql, { restbegin: now, status: 2 });
    }else{
      console.log("error");
    };
  }else if(req.body.end_button){
     if(status_checked == 2){
        var results = await query(updatesql, { restend: now, status: 3 });
     }else{
        console.log("error");
     };

  };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users SET xxx = ?, xxx = ? WHERE xxx = ?
```

として、各If文内にそれぞれもってくることで解決できました。
ありがとうございました。